# Checking Boot Volume

Tags: linux

Programmatically, how can I check whether the lun node is a boot volume or not (the lun node is created under `/dev/` on Linux systems (such as RHEL or Ubuntu or any other linux flavour).

To my knowledge, there is a way to check using the utility like `dd`, `hexdump`, `file`, or by reading the first 512 bytes programmatically, etc (by checking/reading the fist 512 bytes from the lun node).

Is there any other alternative efficient way to do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have not worked with it. So I couldn't test it. But I believe this is what you need. http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/System-Administration/LUN-details-with-mount-point/td-p/4780405#.U6tby5bxXF0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With respect to determining if a partition is bootable you could use `sfdisk` to identify this:

```
$ sudo sfdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 60801 cylinders, 255 heads, 63 sectors/track
Units: cylinders of 8225280 bytes, blocks of 1024 bytes, counting from 0

   Device Boot Start     End   #cyls    #blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *      0+     63-     64-    512000   83  Linux
/dev/sda2         63+  60801-  60738- 487873536   8e  Linux LVM
/dev/sda3          0       -       0          0    0  Empty
/dev/sda4          0       -       0          0    0  Empty
```

Any that are bootable, will have a `*` in the 2nd column of output. For other types of devices such as LVM and SD cards:

```
Disk /dev/mapper/fedora_greeneggs-swap: 997 cylinders, 255 heads, 63 sectors/track

Disk /dev/mapper/fedora_greeneggs-root: 6527 cylinders, 255 heads, 63 sectors/track

Disk /dev/mapper/fedora_greeneggs-home: 53212 cylinders, 255 heads, 63 sectors/track

Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 488672 cylinders, 4 heads, 16 sectors/track
sfdisk: Warning: The partition table looks like it was made
  for C/H/S=*/255/63 (instead of 488672/4/16).
For this listing I'll assume that geometry.

Units: cylinders of 8225280 bytes, blocks of 1024 bytes, counting from 0

   Device Boot Start     End   #cyls    #blocks   Id  System
/dev/mmcblk0p1          0+   1946-   1947-  15633408    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk0p2          0       -       0          0    0  Empty
/dev/mmcblk0p3          0       -       0          0    0  Empty
/dev/mmcblk0p4          0       -       0          0    0  Empty
```

LVM logical volumes (LVs) cannot be bootable, to my knowledge, and the star, `*`, would also apply to these other types of media, such as SD cards.